# How to determine the trees of a graph?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, tree

Given an object `Node` with an attribute `parent`,

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
```

I'm trying to make the following test pass:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def _nodes():
    return {1: Node(),
            2: Node(parent=5),
            3: Node(),
            4: Node(parent=3),
            5: Node(parent=1),
            6: Node(),
            7: Node(parent=6),
            8: Node()
            }

def test_trees(_nodes):
    assert trees(_nodes) == [{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4}, {6, 7}, {8}]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([__file__])
```

So far, I've come up with the following implementation of the `trees` method:

```
def trees(nodes):
    _trees = []
    while nodes:
        for u, node in nodes.items():
            if node.parent is None:
                _trees.append({u})
                nodes.pop(u)
            else:
                for tree in _trees:
                    if node.parent in tree:
                        tree.add(u)
                        nodes.pop(u)
    return _trees
```

However, this implementation 'deletes the input', and on a related problem in my 'real' application I'm getting a `RuntimeError` that the dictionary `mutated during iteration`.

Is there a better way to implement the `trees` method?

Comment: Your test is comparing the output to a list. Is the order in which the `trees` function outputs the trees really important? Shouldn't that be a set of trees instead?

Comment: If I try to modify the `trees` method to make a 'set of sets', I get a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`. The main problem, though, is the mutation of `nodes` during iteration (although I haven't yet been able to pin down why it works for this simple example and not for a more complicated one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized there is a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do, which is to determine the strongly connected components of a graph. In addition to a `parent` attribute, each node also has an 'interval' between which it was discovered and finished (i.e., its adjacency list was fully explored) during depth-first search. The algorithm is such that the intervals of the children are fully contained by those of their parents.

This is also explained by Sedgewick and Wayne, *Algorithms* (4th ed.) as shown below.

[image]